# PIC16F1575 Oscillator Problems

Tags: c, pic

I'm new to PIC programming and I'm trying to set up my PIC to flash an LED using the following code, but nothing is happening:

```c
// PIC16F1575 Configuration Bit Settings

// 'C' source line config statements

// CONFIG1
#pragma config FOSC = INTOSC    // Oscillator Selection Bits (INTOSC oscillator; I/O function on CLKIN pin)
#pragma config WDTE = ON        // Watchdog Timer Enable (WDT enabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config MCLRE = ON       // MCLR Pin Function Select (MCLR/VPP pin function is MCLR)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Flash Program Memory Code Protection (Program memory code protection is disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF      // Brown-out Reset Enable (Brown-out Reset disabled)
#pragma config CLKOUTEN = ON    // Clock Out Enable (CLKOUT function is enabled on the CLKOUT pin)

// CONFIG2
#pragma config WRT = OFF        // Flash Memory Self-Write Protection (Write protection off)
#pragma config PPS1WAY = ON     // PPSLOCK bit One-Way Set Enable bit (PPSLOCKED Bit Can Be Cleared & Set Once)
#pragma config PLLEN = OFF      // PLL Enable (4x PLL disabled)
#pragma config STVREN = ON      // Stack Overflow/Underflow Reset Enable (Stack Overflow or Underflow will cause a Reset)
#pragma config BORV = LO        // Brown-out Reset Voltage Selection (Brown-out Reset Voltage (Vbor), low trip point selected.)
#pragma config LPBOREN = OFF    // Low Power Brown-out Reset enable bit (LPBOR is disabled)
#pragma config DEBUG = OFF      // In-Circuit Debugger Mode (In-Circuit Debugger disabled, ICSPCLK and ICSPDAT are general purpose I/O pins)
#pragma config LVP = ON         // Low-Voltage Programming Enable (Low-voltage programming enabled)

// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.

#include <xc.h>

//TEST programme for PIC16F1575

#include "config.h"

#define _XTAL_FREQ 16000000

void main(void) {
    
    OSCCONbits.IRCF = 0b1111; //setting internal oscillator to 16MHz
    OSCCONbits.SPLLEN = 0b0; //sets PLL disable
    OSCCONbits.SCS = 0b00; //uses FOSC determined clock
    
    OSCTUNEbits.TUN = 0b000000;//tunes oscillator to max frequency
    
    ANSELCbits.ANSC0 = 0; //sets RC0 to digital
    TRISCbits.TRISC0 = 0;//sets RC0 to output
            
    while(1){
        
        LATCbits.LATC0 = 1; //makes RC0 high
        //__delay_ms(1000);
        //LATCbits.LATC0 = 0; //makes RC0 LOW
        //__delay_ms(1000);
    }
    
    return;
}
```

Comment: Is the LED sourced or sunk from the port? How much can the pin source/sink?

Comment: The code as shown (with bits commented out) would not flash anything. Can we assume you are running with the commented out bits actually included?

Comment: You don't reset the watchdog timer. Try to disable IT or include a ClrWdt().

Comment: Hi All, my apologies for the lack of response, thanks for your assistance I managed to get it going. Turns out it was a hardware issue.